# compare between more than 2 vectors in R (Voting)

Tags: r

I have 5 vectors each item in these vectors is either "yes" or "no"
So I want to compare between these 5 vectors (row by row) and calculate the majority voting for each row and add the result to a new vector.
How can I perform that in an effective way.

```
v1=c("yes","no","no","yes")
v2=c("no","no","yes","yes")
v3=c("yes","yes","no","yes")
v4=c("yes","no","yes","yes")
v5=c("yes","yes","yes","no")
#The expected output is "yes", "no", "yes", "yes"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First put the data in a form that is character based:

```
dat <- data.frame( v1=c("yes","no","no","yes"),
                  v2=c("no","no","yes","yes"),
                  v3=c("yes","yes","no","yes"),
                  v4=c("yes","no","yes","yes"),
                  v5=c("yes","yes","yes","no"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

Then pull out the names of the maximum value for a table object:

```
 apply(dat, 1, function(x) names(which.max(table(x))) )
[1] "yes" "no"  "yes" "yes"
```

Comment: It works also if the data is stored as factors as it would be the case with a "standard" data.frame

Answer (score 0):

Another method is to use `mapply` with `==` to return a matrix of TRUE and FALSE comparing where the elements of the vectors are equal to something (here, "yes"). Then `rowMeans` calculates the proportion across rows, and `> 0.5` checks for majority. We add 1 to convert to a numeric position and then use this as a position to choose from the elements in `c("no", "yes")`.

```
c("no", "yes")[(rowMeans(mapply("==", moreArgs=list("yes"), myList)) > 0.5) + 1L]
[1] "yes" "no"  "yes" "yes"
```

An alternative using matrix multiplication is

```
c("no", "yes")[((do.call(cbind, myList) == "yes") %*%
               rep(1, length(myList)) > (length(myList) / 2)) + 1L]
[1] "yes" "no"  "yes" "yes"
```

Note that you start by putting the vectors in a list as below.

**data**

```
myList <- list(v1=c("yes","no","no","yes"),
               v2=c("no","no","yes","yes"),
               v3=c("yes","yes","no","yes"),
               v4=c("yes","no","yes","yes"),
               v5=c("yes","yes","yes","no"))
```